# Remove Status Bar Text (Firefox) when hovering/clicking over a link

Tags: hyperlink, statusbar, status

How can I remove the status bar text when hovering (maybe clicking too) over a link?
I'd like this to have permanent, like when loading the whole page.
Don't want to apply this on every single link...

Is there a way?
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: That’s only possible if the browser’s settings allow it. And why would you want to do this? I want to be able to see where links point to (which is why I have disabled status bar manipulation in my browser).

Comment: thanks for your reply - I would want to do this because I'm building a webbased application in fullscreen mode and the status bar would be a very ugly thing to have - I want to have a full clean website without scrollbars (already managed to remove them onload) and without the status bar text

Comment: Okay, I got a workaround:

I just removed the <a href>-tags and inserted a span with an ID and an onClick-Event with location.href.